# Automatically update client side data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, data-binding

I have a number of controls on an administrator user interface that give various pieces of data derived from the database, i.e. registered users, site visitors, etc, etc. and I'd like to know if there's a way of automatically updating the data on the client side based on updating values in the database.

Essentially, it would be a live feed of the number of registered users, or number of site visitors.

I know it's possible using JavaScript to poll a web service every little while that queries the database to pull out the relevant data, but I was wondering if there's a better way of doing it.

I've had a quick look into Ajax live data binding and jQuery jsView / templating, but from what I can tell, the Ajax live data binding isn't being developed any more and I can't quite tell from reading about jsView if it'll do the trick or not.

Comment: Is there a specific issue with using Javascript, or are you just curious about other alternatives?

Comment: I suggest looking into Websockets.

Comment: I'm just curious about other alternatives

Comment: @KevinB - I'll have a look at WebSockets in more depth tomorrow, quick question though, do you happen to know how backwards compatible they are?  We have a requirement to support the last two versions of IE and occasionally *spits* IE6

Comment: Older browsers do not support it natively, however there are js frameworks for handling it cross-browser that involve flash.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use [SignalIR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki), but it may or may not fit with what you want to do. Asynchronous server-to-client data pushing is something that has never been simple in .Net .

Answer (score 1):

I personally use node.js and Socket.IO to do this for my website, which is basically just a social networking website with almost all data live. I would say this is probably the best way to do this, as polling the database every set seconds gets heavy on the server and is a nightmare.

http://nodejs.org/

http://socket.io/

This is of course quite a lot of complicated work (at first) to get it all installed and working, however it is well worth it once you do, as I have found. Although perhaps it may be too much work and complications for what you want to do, which sounds rather pointless in my opinion, though you may have other reasons for wanting this.